# How to Flash / Repair Soft-Bricked Huawei P30 Lite

Tags: mobile, bootloader, huawei-mobile-services, bios, firmware

Hello Guys I had a little mistake and accidentally Soft-Bricked my Huawei Device. The device keeps on Boot looping. I've already done a SD-Card Update and an Update via DC-Phoenix.

The Update was Successfully but the device hast still no Operating System its just keep on Booting in **eRecovery**, or **fastboot**. Doing a **eRecovery** via Network or Factory Reset does not help.

So now I have no clue what else I can do.

**Phone Information:**

```
Model: MAR-LX1A

Firmware: MAR-L01A 9.1.0.220D(C891E4R2P1)

Vendor: demo

Country: eea

Bootloader FB lock: locked

Bootloader User lock: locked

Firmware Reset Protection (FRP): unlocked
```

Comment: Also use your same account to ask at the [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/) Stack site.